# PHP error with pdo while loop

Tags: php, pdo

Hi I am trying to set a cache of the users information from the database using pdo with php, but it is throwing some errors

Code:

```
public function setUserCache($db)
    {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['user']['id']))
            exit();

        $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail = :mail");
        $statement->execute(array(':mail' => $_SESSION['user']['username']));
        $userData = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


        $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM data WHERE id = :id");
        $statement->execute(array(':id' => $userData['id']));
        $roleplayDate = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        while (list($var, $val) = each($userData)) {
            $_SESSION['user'][$var] = $val;
        }

        while (list($var, $val) = each($roleplayDate[0])) {
            $_SESSION['user'][$var] = $val;
        }
    }
```

The error:

```
E_WARNING Error in file »class.user.php« at line 101: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object
```

Line 101:

```
while (list($var, $val) = each($roleplayDate[0])) {
```

The error happens on BOTH while loops.

Comment: Check if your statement executes correctly, it is possible it returns False, which is not an array or object.

Comment: but `$roleplayDate[0]` isn't an array, `$roleplayDate` is

Comment: consider using var_dump on $userData and $roleplayDate before the loops. The result should give us the clue what's going on

Comment: bool(false) on var_dump

Comment: `$_SESSION['user']['username']` maybe is empty.

Comment: rray's answer was correct.